# Python GIL and deadlock detection?

Tags: python, multithreading, deadlock, gil

When using Python a multi-threaded environment, it is quite easy to deadlock as we need to lock the Python GIL.  While trying to lock the GIL, we may hold other locks and the Python thread holding the GIL may call us trying to get the same lock.   Ideally, we'd have a `PyGILSTATE_TryEnsure()` such that on failure we can examine the locks we hold and raise a "would deadlock" exception.   I couldn't find anything in the Python docs that allows me to do this.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to provide a concrete example that demonstrates this problem.  I would like to understand the situation where you have a potential deadlock situation that would not still exist if there were no GIL.

Comment: Its a classical deadlock situation.   Thread 1 holds lock A and tries to get the GIL, thread 2 holds the GIL and tries to get lock A.   The concrete situation I observed was related to Janus, a project to establish a de-facto standard Prolog <-> Python interface among several Prolog systems.   Lock A was a lock on a Prolog output stream.   One Prolog thread tried to call Python with the output stream locked and a Python thread called Prolog, trying to write to the same output stream.

Comment: You say thread 2 holds the GIL and tries to get lock A, But if the lock cannot be immediately acquired, surely if goes into a wait state until the lock is released and can be acquired. But before it goes into that wait state, surely it first releases the GIL, no? This then gives Thread 1 a chance to acquire the GIL and eventually release the lock it holds. I have written threaded code with locks and *never* have I experienced the deadlock you describe. Is that just me? So post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The implication of your question is that the design of Python is *fatally* flawed in that `threading.Lock` instances cannot reliably be used due to the existence of the GIL. You would think that somebody would have brought this problem up long before now if it were truly a problem. As I said before, if you are having a deadlock situation I don't see how you can blame the GIL; I believe you have some other problem that would exist in the absence of a GIL.

Comment: I think you are right.   Thread 2, running Python code and calling Prolog (which will try to get lock A) can give up the GIL using `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`.  That should allow Thread 1 to continue and release lock A.     In fact, in the meanwhile all calls from Python to Prolog now use `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`/`Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` such that Prolog threads can run concurrent.    Thanks.